# What ip to listen to when handling remote connections? 127.0.0.1 or actual IP?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, wcf, tcp

If I am going to host a TCP Service in WCF, what IP do I listen to if I want to others to remotely connect to it? Currently, I've got it to 127.0.0.1 and am developing locally, so I don't see an issue.

However, if I want others to connect remotely, can I still listen to 127.0.0.1 and trust that others would connect fine with my actual IP?

PS. I don't have a separate computer to test this out and not enough RAM to run a separate VM at this time =(

Comment: You'll probably want to change 127.0.0.1 to * or 0.0.0.0 to allow your endpoint to be connected to by _any_ IP. Connecting to _your local IP_ is tricky if you have multiple local IPs. Imagine the case where your program is installed on a PC with multiple network interfaces... binding to **all** of them is inefficient and wasteful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

127.0.0.1 is only visible to your computer.  So unless you listen on your actual LAN IP address (or WAN if no router), nothing external will be able to see it.

Comment: In this case it would also be valuable to suggest the way to listen to _all_ local IP addresses to avoid problems with multi-NIC situations.

Answer (score 1):

127.0.0.1 is what's called a loopback address. You would need to listen on another interface and IP address for other people to connect.

The interface you're looking for is most likely in one of the following ranges:

```
10.0.0.0/8   ( 10.ANYTIHNG )
172.16.0.0/12  ( 172.16-31.ANYTHING )
192.168.0.0/16 ( 192.168.ANYTHING )
```

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loopback and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_IP_address for more information.

Comment: Please see the FAQ regarding signatures in posts.